# MySQL Distribution of units/order in given year

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a single MySQL query (subqueries are fine) that will get a distribution of units per order over the past year in the following format:

```
units_per_order     |     number_of_orders     |     percent_of_total
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1                   |                 7500     |                  55%
2 
3 
4
5
6-10
10-20
30-50
50–100
100+
```

***EDIT:***

Tables and necessary columns to query against:

```
Table: orders
Fields: orders_id, date_purchased

Table: orders_products
Fields: orders_id, products_quantity
```

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, qty FROM (
        SELECT SUM(products_quantity) as qty, orders_id
        FROM orders_products op LEFT JOIN orders o USING (orders_id)
        WHERE date_purchased LIKE '2012%'
        GROUP BY orders_id
    ) AS new_table WHERE qty != 0 GROUP BY qty ORDER BY qty
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are your ideas? What is the structure of your data?

Comment: you can group/order on arbitrary expression, but you'd probably be better off doing such things in php, as doing it in sql will just make the query hideously ugly. plus getting that `%` within the query is essentially impossible without doing nested queries. figuring out a % requires knowing data that isn't available until AFTER the query's done, but you need the % inserted into the query WHILE it's building the result set.

Comment: @Tim N, I was looking more for theory that I could then apply to my structure, but I suppose it would make it much easier to give an answer if I give the structure. Sorry about that, I'll edit this momentarily.

Comment: @MarcB SQL is a fine place to have this logic, and finding the total number of units is just one simple query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I ended up with. Please advise if you see any way to make it more efficient.

```
SELECT qty, cnt, ROUND(((cnt / total) * 100)) AS percent FROM (
    SELECT qty, COUNT(*) AS cnt, total
    FROM (
        SELECT
            (
                CASE WHEN (SUM(products_quantity) < 6) THEN SUM(products_quantity)
                    WHEN (SUM(products_quantity) BETWEEN 6 AND 10) THEN 6
                    WHEN (SUM(products_quantity) BETWEEN 11 AND 20) THEN 11
                    WHEN (SUM(products_quantity) BETWEEN 21 AND 50) THEN 21
                    WHEN (SUM(products_quantity) BETWEEN 51 AND 100) THEN 51
                    ELSE 101
                END
            ) AS qty,
            orders_id,
            (
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(orders_id))
                FROM orders JOIN orders_products USING (orders_id)
                WHERE date_purchased LIKE '2012%' AND products_quantity != 0
            ) AS total
        FROM orders_products op JOIN orders o USING (orders_id)
        WHERE date_purchased LIKE '2012%'
        GROUP BY orders_id
    ) AS new_table
    WHERE qty != 0 GROUP BY qty
) AS newer_table
```